# Is it true that a word 航空母舰 (lit. "an aircraft carrier") can be used as an euphemism or a joke for a "woman with big breasts" or "plump woman"?

Tags: euphemism

I've seen such a weird translation of a word 航空母舰 in an online dictionary but could not find any actual usage of the word in the described context. Was it a mistake or a kind of a joke?

Comment: I have never heard that. Do you mean _fleet girls_ (characters) in [Kantai Collection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kantai_Collection) like games?

Comment: I just find out an article discuss the _big breasts_ with big ship: [大艦巨乳主義](https://dic.pixiv.net/a/%E5%A4%A7%E8%89%A6%E5%B7%A8%E4%B9%B3%E4%B8%BB%E7%BE%A9). But the article (and the word described) is in Japanese. [Some Chinese articles](https://mzh.moegirl.org/zh-hans/%E8%88%B0%E9%98%9FCollection/%E7%94%A8%E8%AF%AD#%E5%A4%A7%E8%88%B0%E5%B7%A8%E4%B9%B3%E4%B8%BB%E4%B9%89) mentioned this word (maybe translated from Japanese) after video game _KanColle_. But I didn't see any usage like this in Chinese.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there shouldn't be such relation. I can guess where you might see this weird relation between aircraft carriers and women with large breasts. This connection often appears in warship personification animations/drawings/games, among which the Japanese game KanColle (舰队Collection) is probably the most famous one around the world.

The reason behind is that authors of animes/drawings often relate the tonnage of a warship (not only aircraft carriers, but also battleships and sometimes even heavy cruisers) to their breast sizes. In a warship personification game, if an aircraft carrier character is designed/drawn with flat breasts, she will probably become a popular topic among players for a long time. For example, among games developed in China, the Saratoga aircraft carrier in the game Azur Lane (碧蓝航线) and Hood battlecruiser in the game Warship Girls (战舰少女) are those who break the breast-tonnage rule.

As a summary, please do NOT try to use this word to *describe anyone in real life*. Among warship games players, they might understand what you are referring to. But for most people outside this group, they probably get confused, or even worse, treat this as impolite or offensive. We can make fun of game characters in some cases, but never of a true person.

Answer (score 1):

航空母舰  is huge, you can use it as a euphemism for something big in size, same as other huge objects, but it is not commonly used to describe woman's breasts, for that, we use other object like basketball, torpedo or water melon, something that resemble the shape of a breast

If you compare a woman to a 航空母舰, you are suggesting she is big in size in general, not just her breasts

Comment: LOL, you learn something new everyday. If 航空母舰, (which is the official term for an aircraft carrier), could be taken to mean, in Chinese, women with big breasts, then it's nothing new because there is an English shanty called "That's Where My Money Goes" which has a verse --  "She's got a pair of hips, just like two battle ships" In colloquial Chinese, the term for opposite of "big breasts" is also aviation related, = "飞机场", (think flat runway?, so be warned) But, seriously, the "proper" term for "big tits" in Chinese is 大山雀; with 山雀 being a member of the "Tits" family of birds.

Comment: @WayneCheah I had never head this usage of `大山雀` either. Is this word used in some dialect?